# Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [cmd.exe] on Pycharm 2019.1.3

Tags: pycharm

When trying to run my django application in Pycharm, I get the below error.

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [cmd.exe] in <myappfilepath>
```

I've tried rebooting and redownloading Pycharm, opening it with administrator permissions and changing the terminal settings to run powershell.exe instead of cmd.exe with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was permission in bitdefender

Comment: I don't use bitdefender, so I don't think that could have been the problem. A few days later, when starting Pycharm, the problem was fixed. Not sure how that happened...

Comment: For me it was the 2 weeks trial version of malwarebytes